# JQuery post has issues with the @ symbol

Tags: jquery, regex

I have an form with a email field that i want to verify against a MySQL database on keyup(). I have tried this with the username field as well and had no problems doing this. But for some reason the value of the email does not post to the php function or return anything from the controller the moment you onKeyUp() the @ symbol. a email has the @ located somwhere in the middle of the email address e.g piet@pompies.com, the "piet" posts fine untill you hit the shift 2 (@) then everything goes down the drain. here is the code:

```
$( "#emailField" ).keyup(function(){

    var email = $("#emailField").val();

    $.post( "<?php echo URL_CHECK_EMAIL_EXISTS; ?>" + email, function( data ) {

        alert(email);

    });

});
```

Here is the controller function, even though i said everything works fine with normal strings such as the username.

```
 public function check_email($email){

    $exists = $this->User_Model->if_email_exists($email);

    if($exists){

        echo "true";

    } else {

        echo "false";

    }

}
```

Here is the model, which works fine:

```
public function if_email_exists($email){

    $this->db
    ->from('users')
    ->where('email', $email)
    ->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: I would suggest not to make DB calls on onKeyUp events unless its absolutely neccessary.. Too much DB calls isnt that good ;)

Comment: ^^^ This!!  Also, check the documentation on how to send data with an ajax post call.  You don't put it in the url.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: MVC is the reason the value is in the url

Comment: A value should be in URL if its get request. i dont believe MVC *requires* form values to be in URL

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURI` to encode email address before posting it to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A Raw code which you can try would be like this

```
$( "#emailField" ).blur(function(){ // u can also use focusout event

var email = $("#emailField").val().trim();
// Check for email validity using regex
 if(email_valid){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'url here',
        data: { email :  email }
         }).done(function(resp){
              alert(resp)
         });
}else{
   alert('Invalid Email)
  }
});
```